# jquery sortable border collapse chrome safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, webkit, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery `sortable()` on a table with `border-collapse: collapse`. Something strange happens with the spacing between the rows in Chrome and Safari. It seems ok in IE, FF, & Opera.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/benstenson/LMqNH/

1. `border-collapse: separate` is one option.
2. Calling `$('table').hide.show(0)` on the sortable() stop event is another option.

Anyone know what the problem is?

Here is a screenshot after moving the rows around.

[image]

Comment: don't see anything obviously wrong when i view that jsfiddle (Chromium 13 on Debian) -- can you give more info.?

Comment: @simon I think the problem occurs when you reorder one of the inside rows (like 2 or 3) - it doubles the size of the border between one or more rows. Eventually it even creates white space between rows.

Comment: @Benjamin I can confirm your issue, but don't see any solutions that work. looks related to this, but their solution doesn't work: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/sortable-problem-on-chrome-browser.  Only thing I have found that works is removing the td border completely! not ideal obviously...

Comment: @mutex, the `border-spacing:0` didn't work for me either. I will probably use `border-collapse: separate` in the meantime. I wonder why `table.hide().show(0)` fixes it but `table.hide().show()` doesn't. Maybe there is an answer in there somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on this for a while.  The closest I've been able to achieve is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/rogerblanton/EtC2E/1/

I changed a little bit of the CSS to put the border on something different and it looks pretty close if not exactly what you want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: that's cool you got it working! I think I'd be in too many places to change the html as a fix. I'm sure it will be useful to someone though. For me it is not urgent enough to mess with it. I'd prefer to understand what actually causes the problem or see it fixed either in future jQuery or Chrome. Thanks!